# set config on salt minion from salt master

Tags: salt-stack

I need to set the saltstack configuration of a salt minion from a salt master. The `salt.modules.config` only appears to support *getting* configuration from the minion.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.config.html

```
salt '*' config.get file_roots
```

returns the `file_roots` from each minion, but surprisingly you can't execute

```
salt '*' config.set file_roots <custom configuration>
```

The only solution I can think of is to edit the `/etc/salt/minion` file using the `salt.states.file` module (https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html)  and restart the `salt-minion` service. However, I have a hunch there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, Salt can Salt itself!

We use the [salt-formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/salt-formula) to salt minions. The master might also be salted using this formula.

Answer (score 0):

You should manage the files in `/etc/salt/minion.d/` using Salt states.

An example (there are other ways to manage the restart):

```yaml
/etc/salt/minion.d/default_env.conf:
  file.serialize:
    - dataset:
        saltenv: base
        pillarenv_from_saltenv: true
    - formatter: yaml

/etc/salt/minion.d/logging.conf:
  file.serialize:
    - dataset:
        log_fmt_console: '[%(levelname)s] %(message)s %(jid)s'
        log_fmt_logfile: '%(asctime)s,%(msecs)03d [%(name)-17s][%(levelname)-8s] %(message)s %(jid)s'
        logstash_udp_handler:
          host: logstash
          port: 10514
          version: 1
          msg_type: saltstack
    - formatter: yaml

salt-minion:
  service.running:
    - enable: true
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/salt/minion.d/*

Stop state.apply to allow minion restart:
  test.fail_without_changes:
    - order: 1
    - failhard: true
    - onchanges:
      - service: salt-minion
```