# How do I restart salt-minion without causing the state to fail?

Tags: salt-stack

We use a salt state to update the `saltenv` and `pillarenv` in `/etc/salt/minion`
we call this initial state with the `state.apply app.changesaltenv saltenv=newenv pillarenv=newenv`

I haven't figured out a way to have the salt state restart the minion without it causing the salt state to fail because it loses connectivity with the salt minion.

If I try to add `service.restart` to the state, the state fails because the minion stops communicating with the master.

I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576837/set-config-on-salt-minion-from-salt-master) but the examples does so by causing a failure.

Comment: as the only answer is yours, you should probably accept it

Answer (score 0):

After asking around I got this suggestion and it works so far.

It does make an assumption about where salt-call is and I can't find a salt variable that easily exposes where salt-call.bat is. I can write some jinja that checks `grains['saltpath']` to determine if salt was installed to `C:\salt` or  `C:\Program Files\Salt Project\Salt` or possibly someplace else.

```yaml
Restart Salt Minion:
  cmd.run:
{%- if grains['kernel'] == 'Windows' %}
    - name: 'C:\salt\salt-call.bat service.restart salt-minion'
{%- else %}
    - name: 'salt-call service.restart salt-minion'
{%- endif %}
    - bg: True
    - order: last
```

<sub>Answer originally by [Greg Long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12469232/greg-long).</sub>

Comment: As long as `salt-call.bat` is on the `%PATH%`, you shouldn't need the Jinja logic