# How to Update Salt-minion agent

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to update the salt minion agent to the next version but I am getting the following as expected.

```
 Minion did not return. [No response]
```

I tried the following:

```
Minion_Upgrade:
  module.run:
    - name: pkg.update
    - pkgs:
      - salt-minion


Start_Minion_Service:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        exec 0>&- # close stdin
        exec 1>&- # close stdout
        exec 2>&- # close stderr
        nohup /bin/sh -c 'salt-call --local service.restart salt-minion.service' &


sleep_30_sec:
  module.run:
    - test.sleep:
      - length: 30
    - require:
      - Start_Minion_Service


check_salt_minion_status:
  cmd.run:
    - name: systemctl status salt-minion.service
    - require:
      - Start_Minion_Service
```

It did not work.

Is there a workaround to bypass this issue?

Comment: The `pkg.update` restarts the minion. That's what you have to defer.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76189951/476716 but nobody has upvoted an answer yet.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed answer, The Server already has the agent (salt-minion). I want to upgrade the agent version.

Comment: What's that an answer to?

Comment: I am answering to your comment: 

The pkg.update restarts the minion.

Comment: That wasn't a question. Your problem is because `pkg.update` restarts the minion.

Comment: I do not know another way to install another version of salt-minion on the server. The issue is that during the provisioning of the VM the minion is installed by default. 

Do you know any other approach? 

Thank you.

Comment: See the linked question

Comment: Another workaround is to create a bash script which will install new salt-minion version and execute it from saltmaster using the below state:

Service:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "./test.sh > /tmp/update_status.txt" | at now + 1 minutes
    - cwd: /tmp
    - runas: root

Comment: that has multiple unnecessary steps